# Visa in my maiden name

Tags: visas

I have a valid US B1/B2 visa under my maiden name on a separate passport. I understand that I am allowed to travel for business purposes provided I carry both my passports and my original marriage certificate. My question is what name should my tickets be booked under? My legal (married name) or maiden name?

Answer (score 8):

You should book your flights under the same name as the passport you will be using to board the flight.  If you have a new passport with your new name, then you should use your new name to book your tickets.

We've been in this exact same situation before: when we got married, my wife had her USA B1/B2 visa in her passport with her maiden name in it.  Later, she obtained a new passport with her new name on it - and the old passport was cancelled and returned to her.  The next time we travelled to the USA, she used her new passport (with her new name) to book tickets - and took her old passport and our marriage certificate with her.

When entering the USA, she presented all three things to the border agent - and got through without any issues.